# Are upper and lower bounds equivalent to rows and columns in Java 2D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been having some issues trying to make sense of Java's 2D arrays. I've read about upper and lower bounds, are they equivalent to rows and columns or am I misinterpreting something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why downvote this? If I'm really that off about how it works I'd like to know.

Comment: Again? Is it just because it's a newbie question? I feel like that's kind of an abuse of the down vote privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] arr = new int[x][y];
```

A two dimensional array is essentially an array of arrays. You could think of them as rows and columns, but they're really showing this:

```
arr = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
```

Which you can think of as:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Comment: So what are upper and lower bounds though? Is it the same as rows and columns?

Comment: Not really. There are no "rows and columns" in that sense, but a two dimensional array can be thought of as a grid like I've shown above. In my definition of `arr`, your upper bound would be `x` and your lower bound would be `y`. `x` and `y` are your size limits: in a regular array (`int[] arr = new int[z]`), `z` would be your limit on the size. It's the same type of deal here, but in this two-dimensional way.